# Swift - pickerView components' separator

Tags: swift

I am currently working on 3 components(columns) picker in my app.
I want to put border line between 0 - 1 components and 1 - 2 components. It seems fairly fundamental thing but I cannot find a way to do so.

Is there anyone who knows how to make the lines?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
picker.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
picker.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

[swift-formatting-a-uipickerview](https://makeapppie.com/2014/10/21/swift-swift-formatting-a-uipickerview/)